# Allow application through firewall Linux

Tags: linux, centos, firewall

I installed clean CentOS 8 machine. copied my app to it. started. i can get response by

`curl https://localhost:5001 -- insecure`

but if I try a local or external ip or browser from remote location for example

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port 5001/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload

curl https://10.128.0.10:5001 -- insecure
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.128.0.10 port 5001: Connection refused
```

Comment: This is caused by your application, not the firewall (which is correctly configured).

Comment: yes, so when I curl localhost my app listens to the port and when I curl it differently it doesnt.. great.. thanks so much.. you opened whole new world for me